# Check if JSON value empty in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, null

Imagine a table which tracks baseball pitchers like so...

```
     +------------+--------------------+-------+
     | id | name               | secondary_pitch |
     +------------+--------------------+-------+
     | 13 | Chris Sale         | ['Curveball','Slider'] |
     | 14 | Justin Verlander   | ['Fastball','Changeup'] |
     | 15 | CC Sabathia        | ['Fastball','Curveball'] |
     | 16 | Sonny Grey         |    ['Slider'] |
     | 17 | Aldoris Chapman    |    [] |
     +------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Notice the secondary_pitch column has a JSON value. So if a pitcher, like Chapman, has no secondary pitch, it will not return null, instead it returns an empty JSON string ('[]').

How then can I get a count of the number of pitchers who have no secondary pitch?

I can't do...

```
  select count(*) from pitchers where secondary_pitch is null
```

Comment: What's the benefit of putting a Json file in your column? (I would redesign the table)

Comment: All the "array types" like `['Curveball','Slider']` are invalid JSON so NONE of MySQL's native JSON (like `JSON_LENGTH`, `JSON_SEARCH` or `JSON_EXTRACT` saw a couple of answers with it) functions would work... `["Curveball","Slider"]` is valid JSON then the MySQL native JSON functions should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check where secondary_pitch is (null) or '' (empty string)

```
SELECT count(*) from pitchers WHERE secondary_pitch IS NULL OR secondary_pitch = '';
```

also you can use like this.

```
SELECT count(*) from pitchers WHERE secondary_pitch LIKE '%[]%'
```

Comment: a JSON (`[]`) empty json array element is not equal to `NULL` or `' '` so this won't work..

Comment: So you can use it like this "LIKE '%[]%' "

Comment: I chose this answer because all the other answers required a JSON function which I don't have access to since I have read only permissions on that DB[Code: 1370, SQL State: 42000]  execute command denied to user 'jjreadonly'@'%' for routine 'turnto_summary.JSON_SEARCH'

Comment: Downvoted because this is not working (tested with MySQL 8.0.15).

Answer (score 47):

I think you can just use `json_length()`:

```
where json_length(secondary_pitch) = 0
```

Comment: Wont work the data (for example `['Curveball','Slider']`) is invalid JSON..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why? It works perfectly. List with 0 items have 0 length in `json_length`

Comment: "Why? It works perfectly" Why? @jsnceo because `["Curveball", "Slider"]` is valid JSON check it on https://jsonlint.com/ `['Curveball','Slider']` does not valid here you should not risk using invalid JSON annywhere in anny programming language even if it "works" MySQL should have given a error on `['Curveball','Slider']`.. In short the string values and key in a JSON array or Object needs to be double quoted thats the JSON standard

Comment: What you're looking at is how mySQL is representing the result of a select.  Everything here is valid.

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) to get first value from your column and check for not null

```
where JSON_EXTRACT(`secondary_pitch`, '$[0]') is not null
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oXv3RwJVVjRVRuQTuVZA61/0)

Comment: @RaymondNijland check the demo link, it will work with double quotes not with single quote

Comment: The data with double qoutes is indeed valid JSON then the JSON function works. You should mention in the answer that the topicstarters current JSON data is invalid JSON

Answer (score 6):

I see this is not answering original question of matching against empty array (`[]`) but this has worked for me, matching against empty dictionary (`{}`), at mysql `5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)`.

I used [JSON_OBJECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) function but it is very likely the [JSON_ARRAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) will also work in similar way, creating the 'empty' object when called without arguments.

If I wanted to match against the json column `vmkeys` value of `{}` (empty dictionary), I used the following query:

```sql
SELECT vmkeys FROM `labinstances` WHERE vmkeys=JSON_OBJECT()
```

To match against the `vmkeys` value of NULL, I used this:

```sql
SELECT vmkeys FROM `labinstances` WHERE vmkeys is NULL
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you! Updating to proper nulls: `update items set tags = null where tags = JSON_OBJECT(); `

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 
JSON_SEARCH(secondary_pitchers, 'all', '') 
    IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Wont work the data (for example `['Curveball','Slider']`) is invalid JSON..